# MongoDB aggregate sum of each element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document:

```
    [
  {
    "name": "firstEntry",
    "values": [
      1,
      3
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "secondEntry",
    "values": [
      9,
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

My final objective is the get sum of each element. For example:

```
final:[10,8]
```

So basically each element in the "final" array with n elements is the sum of each element in the "value" array with n elements.

- final[0] = (document1)values[0]+(document2)values[0]
- final[1] = (document1)values[1]+(document2)values[1]

I have tried the following but keep getting stuck after "unwind" stage and don't know how to proceed.

```
db.entries.aggregate ({
    "$unwind": { path: "$values" }
},{
"$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "index" : "$arrayIndex",
            }
   }});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please find query below - it can be a  case to remodel output, but main goal is achieved: [Below example requires mongo 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.titanium.aggregate ([
{$unwind:{
        path: "$values" ,
        includeArrayIndex:"arrayIndex"
}},
{
    $group:{
        _id:"$arrayIndex",
        valueCount:{ $sum : "$values"}
}},
{
    $group:{
        _id:1, // this is to have someting for grouping
        final:{$push:"$valueCount"}}}
])
```

> { "_id" : 1, "final" : [ 8, 10 ] }

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully.